# Base64 encode from name for email

Tags: php

Why does the opencart [mail class](https://github.com/opencart/opencart/blob/master/upload/system/library/mail.php) encode the senders name?

```
$header .= 'From: ' . '=?UTF-8?B?' . base64_encode($this->sender) . '?=' . '<' . $this->from . '>' . $this->newline;
```

Is this an old technique? I haven't seen it like this before.

Are there any disadvantages to encoding it?

Comment: no harm in it if you specify "Content-Transfer-Encoding" see http://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc2045#section-6.8 and http://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc5322

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Quoted from Wikipedia:

> This is to ensure that the data remain intact without modification
>   during transport. Base64 is commonly used in a number of applications
>   including email via MIME.
>   [Base64](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Base64)
>
> The MIME standard introduced character set specifiers and two content
>   transfer encodings to enable transmission of non-ASCII data: quoted
>   printable for mostly 7 bit content with a few characters outside that
>   range and base64 for arbitrary binary data.
>   [Content Encoding](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Email#Content_encoding)