# In symfony 1.4, using swiftmailer, setTo with parentheses in name breaks message sending

Tags: symfony-1.4, swiftmailer

I am having issues sending mail with swift mailer when Recipient name contains parentheses `(` and `)`

example code:

```
$mail = new Swift_Message();
$mail->setTo('recipient@test.com', 'Recipient (bla bla)');
$mail->setFrom('sender@test.com', 'Sender');
$mail->setSubject('Test email');
$mail->setBody('<html><body><h3>Hello</h3></body></html>', 'text/html');
sfContext::getInstance()->getMailer()->send($mail);
```

If the recipient is using gmail, he does receive the email but when clicking on the down arrow to get more info, The to: part is empty:

[image: Missing to: part]

The problem is some other email services does not receive that email.

As for the original message content, it's too much details to black out to show here but basically my question is how can I use parentheses without breaking anything.

Answer (score 0):

Seems like base64_encode can help so I modified the swiftmailer class **`SimpleMessage.php`** to be sure this fix is applied every time.

**Modification of SimpleMessage from this:**

```
public function setTo($addresses, $name = null)
{
  if (!is_array($addresses) && isset($name))
  {
    $addresses = array($addresses => $name);
  }

  if (!$this->_setHeaderFieldModel('To', (array) $addresses))
  {
    $this->getHeaders()->addMailboxHeader('To', (array) $addresses);
  }
  return $this;
}
```

**To this:**

```
public function setTo($addresses, $name = null)
{
  // if $name is set, encode it
  if(isset($name))
  {
    $name = $this->encodeName($name);
  }

  // if $addresses is an non numeric array (email => name), encode each name.
  if(is_array($addresses) && array_keys($addresses) !== range(0, count($addresses) - 1))
  {
    foreach($addresses as $key => $value)
    {
      $addresses[$key] = $this->encodeName($value);;
    }
  }

  if (!is_array($addresses) && isset($name))
  {
    $addresses = array($addresses => $name);
  }

  if (!$this->_setHeaderFieldModel('To', (array) $addresses))
  {
    $this->getHeaders()->addMailboxHeader('To', (array) $addresses);
  }
  return $this;
}

/**
 * Encode the name to avoid issues with some characters
 *
 * @param string $name
 * @return string
 */
private function encodeName($name)
{
  return "=?UTF-8?B?". base64_encode($name) . '?=';
}
```

This answer helped me: [Base64 encode from name for email](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14377509/base64-encode-from-name-)